# Create model in a custom path in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to create a model in a custom path. If i write the php artisan command like the following it will create model inside app.

```
php artisan make:model core
```

But i want to create the model file inside the custom made Models folder. How can i do it ?

Comment: Please note that this question is written for a **Laravel version lower than version 8**. Since in that version, the default folder for models has been changed to be `app/Models` by default, just like OP of the question wants. https://laravel-news.com/new-features-coming-to-laravel-8

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just define the path where you want to create model.

```
php artisan make:model <directory_name>/<model_name>
```

e.g.

```
php artisan make:model Models/core
```

Comment: If i create a folder inside the Models folder, then what will be the command ? Is it `php artisan make:model Models/Core/core`

Comment: Note that migration will utilize <model_name>, "core" in this case. So it may conflict if you use directories to differ namespace

Answer (score 4):

You can do it easily with custom directory of your Models Folder (I assume Models Folder is sub folder of App). 
Just use this command `php artisan make:model Models/core` then you will get your desire result.
Thanks.