# Laravel Events and Listeners

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-events

This is my event class when i use

```
class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        /**
         * The event listener mappings for the application.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $listen = [
            Registered::class    => [
                SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
            ],
            CategoryEvent::class => [
                CategoryCreatedListener::class,
            ]
        ];
```

when i runs the following command

```
php artisan event:generate
```

it creates the event and listener both in the service provider directory if I put namespace before the event and listener like

```
App\Events\CategoryEvent::class
```

It still creates **App\Event and App\Event** in Service Provider Directory how to Create the Event and Listener Directory up in the App Namespace.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a namespacing issue. You may want to make sure these classes are aliased:

```
use App\Events\Registered;
use App\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification;
...
```

otherwise `Registered::class` is going to be `App\Providers\Registered`.

Comment: thanks, I've searched google and found a solution and worked for me. event_name and listener name needs to be in quotes and doesn't require the **event_name::class** part. But then the Pycharm suggests that it should be like **event_name::class' but it works with that warnning.

Comment: nothing **has** to be a string literal you are just not referencing the correct classes when using `Class::class`, hence the namespacing issue   `\App\Events\Registered::class === 'App\Events\Registered'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Laravel does not have a custom path support for event generation. So your best bet is probably just to create it manually in the directory you want it and insert it into the EventServiceProvider yourself. It's a bit of manual work, but it doesn't take more than a minute to do.

Similar question has already gone through this: [How do I create Events/Listeners with artisan command at sub-directory level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58202475/how-do-i-create-events-listeners-with-artisan-command-at-sub-directory-level)

Comment: @ServerinDK I've found the solution thanks for your help. I think the problem is with the syntax caus older version uses different syntax from the laravel 7., and i havn't worked in older version so thats why facing such problems.